# Is there a way to rebuild python on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

Some downloads are failing due to Python not being built with the `--enable-shared` tag, is there some way to get rid of the version I have and rebuild python? Or even better, just change it without reinstalling?

Comment: I don't know about Ubuntu, but some Linux flavors (CentOS, RHEL) *rely* on the system's version of Python. I think it might not be a good idea to get rid of it.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`?

Answer (score 1):

You can install different Python versions (side-by-side even) using pythonz: http://saghul.github.io/pythonz/

Basically, after installing it, you run a command to download and install Python with the version you want:

```
pythonz install 3.5.1
```

To pass custom compiling options, use `--configure "... options here"` [as per documentation here](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz#install-some-pythons).

It even supports PyPy and Jython.

I've been using it with success for the past year or so, it has made my life of testing projects in different Python versions much easier -- highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild python, and pass `--enable-shared` to `./configure`
Just follow:

For python 3:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python

For Python 2:
https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#building-python

Be careful with the things in your distribution that require python, make sure you set the `Python Path` properly. And check if any of them requires any special configuration flags.

Comment: sweet, that's what I ended up doing. Now where do I change which python is used? I would think in .bashrc but that path points to /usr/local/bin rather than usr/local/lib where my different versions of python are

Comment: @ChandlerSquires You can add the new location you wish to the `$PATH`  with `PATH=$PATH:/data/myscripts`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I want - I need packages that rely on python to be built using the new version, not just to run this version of python when I type python. I thought that the path variable just let said what modules to include in the interpreter.

Comment: oh, in your `\usr\bin` there are symlinks to python. you just need to erase them and replace them by the new ones with `ln`

Answer (score 0):

Get sources with:

```
apt-get source python2.7
```

in the downloaded directory, change in `python2.7.../debian/rules`:

```
with_interp := static
#with_interp := shared
```

to

```
#with_interp := static
with_interp := shared
```

Then at the same level as the `debian` directory, run `dpkg-buildpackage`. You'll get ready `.deb` packages one directory higher. Just install them with `dpkg -i python2.7.....deb`